# The Requested Resources was not found or you do not have sufficient permissions to view it

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Dynamics crm when retrieving value and updating it into another entity it showing like
The Requested Resources was not found or you do not have sufficient permissions to view it

i specified update ids like
               enobj.Id=(Guid)context.OutputParameters["id"];
message:create
service :update on another entity
[image: The Requested resources not available]

this is my code:

```
Query Expression query = new Query Expression();
query.EntityName = en.LogicalName;
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_amount");
var x = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
Entity enobj = new Entity("new_product"); 
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in x.Entities)
{   
    i = i + (int)item.Attributes["new_amount"];
    enobj.Attributes["new_grandtotal"] = i;
}

enobj.Id=(Guid)context.OutputParameters["id"];

// en.Id = enobj.Id;
enobj.Id = en.Id;
service.Update(enobj);
```

message:create 
service :update

i have two entites product and productlineitems

in productlineitems iam creating a record with the field amount 50 after creating that value.iam updating on product entity.
 again i create productlineitem 2 with the value some 90.iam adding 50+90 =140
again lineitem 3 with the value. iam taking that on product entity

message:create   --- productlineitems
service :update  --- product
[image]

Comment: Please show your code and error details.

Comment: Is this plugin registered on Create of Product Entity?

Comment: Why you are assigning value twice to `enobj.Id`

Comment: YOur error message is clear enough. Either you don't have sufficient permissions to update or you are trying to update an object which does not exist. Check you are assigning right Id to `enobj.Id` while updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to update `Product` with `Product Line` Id. Try the following:

Replace

```
enobj.Id = en.Id;
```

With

```
// set the field name (key) based on what you got in system
enobj.Id = (Guid)en["new_productid"];
```

Also, Calling Context is set to `Current user`. So make sure that user have permissions to update Product.

Comment: i tried your code An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code basically the plugin is when productlineitems create with value.that valu iam taking and incrementing on product

Comment: @HskSrinivas I can't guess key. You need to find the name of product's entity reference on ProductLine and extract the Id from Entity reference.

Comment: above error is because new_productid is not the actual field name in this line `enobj.Id = (Guid)en["new_productid"];` You need to find out the field name and replace new_productid with it.

Comment: i tried all this en.Id = enobj.Id;
                enobj.Id = en.Id;
                enobj.Id = (Guid)context.OutputParameters["id"];
                context.OutputParameters["id"] = enobj.Id;

Comment: `en` is your target entity so `en.Id = enobj.Id` does not make any sense. Please do some study about plugins, Dynamics CRM and C#

Comment: Step 1: from target entity (en) extract productId. Step 2: set enobj.Id = productId.

Comment: you are trying to update a value on new_product entity. So you need to give an identifier which reefers to product. en.Id is referring to ProductLine. Good Luck

Comment: ok,very thankfull for replying.plz keep replying on my questions in future

Comment: @Scorpion kudos to your patience :) +1